# How to annotate calculations?

Tags: equations, calculations, annotations

I am writing a basic mathematics book and I would like to annotate some calculations, using arrows, underlines, horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines, boxes, circles, etc., with different colors, to provide a visual aid to the reader. Here is an example (please disregard the wrong explanations and visual clutter):

[image: Example of annotated calculation]
Is there any specific package for this task? (A few weeks ago, I came across a site that explained something along those lines. I don't remember exactly, but it looks like they used the "amsmath" package for that functionality.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a good idea... That said, you should be able to do this using the `tikzmark` package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Searching for `tikzmark cancel` should give you some ideas on how to get started. Basic idea is to use `\tikzmark` (which is available in the `{tikzmark}` package) to make specific point in the text, then _after_ the text is written (include the any necessary space for the drawing), to `overlay` the drawing. I suggest you start with one of the examples and see how far you get on one of those specific drawing issues. If you get stuck and have a specific question about a specific issue, please post a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using `tikzmark`. The command is `\tikzmarknode{<label>}{<content>}`. You can use several of these in your equation with different labels. Then use the options `remember picture, overlay` in a `tikzpicture` and use Ti*k*Z commands to draw the various annotations.

[image]

The code uses a variety of libraries other than `tikzmark`: `shapes.geometric` is used for the ellipse, `shapes.arrows` is used for the "result" arrow, `fit` is used to contain the contents of the red ellipse, blue rectangle and yellow circle, `bending` is used to improve the arrowhead of the blue arrow.

**Remember, when using `tikzmark` you must compile twice after any changes to the node positions.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, shapes.geometric, shapes.arrows, fit, bending}

\begin{document}

\[
\tikzmarknode{a1}{\frac{4}{2}}+\tikzmarknode{a2}{\frac{6}{3}}=
\frac{\tikzmarknode{b1}{(3\times 4)}+\tikzmarknode{b2}{(2\times 6)}}{\tikzmarknode{b3}{2\times 3}}=\tikzmarknode{c1}{\frac{12+12}{6}}=\tikzmarknode{c2}{\frac{24}{6}}=\tikzmarknode{d1}{4}
\]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, font=\sffamily]
\draw[red, thick, ->, shorten <=1em, , shorten >=1em](a2.south east)--node[below, pos=.45, scale=.4]{1}(a1.north west);
\node[draw=red, thick, ellipse, fit=(b1), inner ysep=0, inner xsep=-1mm](ell){};
\draw[thick, red] (ell)--++(0,.5)node[above, red, scale=.4]{This is important!};
\draw[red, thick] (b2.south west)--node[above=2mm, red, scale=.5]{\bfseries WRONG!}(b2.north east);
\draw[green!70!black, thick] (b3.east)--node[below]{$\uparrow$}node[below=5mm, align=left, green!70!black, scale=.5]{This multiplication is not\\necessary Try to simplify.}(b3.west) ([yshift=2pt]b3.east)--([yshift=2pt]b3.west);
\node[draw=blue, thick, fit=(c1), inner xsep=1pt](box){};
\draw[blue, thick, ->, shorten >=3pt] (box) to[out=90, in=90] (c2.north);
\node[draw=yellow!70!orange, thick, circle, fit=(d1), inner sep=1pt](cir){};
\node[draw=yellow!70!orange, thick, text=yellow!70!orange, single arrow, shape border rotate=180, anchor=west, scale=.4, single arrow tip angle=40, minimum height=30mm] at (cir.east){\quad RESULT};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler (but ***not*** as powerful as `tikzmark`) package would be the `annotate-equations` package.

Here a short example taken from the package documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{annotate-equations}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\eqnhighlightheight}{\vphantom{\hat{H}}\mathstrut} 
\begin{equation*}
i \tikzmarknode{hbar}{\mathstrut\hbar} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \eqnmarkbox[blue]{Psi1}{\Psi(x, t)} = \eqnmark[red]{Hhat}{\hat{H}} \eqnmarkbox[blue]{Psi2}{\Psi(x, t)}
\end{equation*}
\annotate[yshift=3em]{above}{hbar}{$\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi}$, reduced Planck constant} 
\annotate[yshift=1em]{above}{Hhat}{Hamilton operator} 
\annotatetwo[yshift=-1em]{below}{Psi1}{Psi2}{Wave function}

\end{document}
```

[image: annotate-equations package]

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Thank you for providing the annotate-equations code.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Your code is such a concise solution ... something I should have at least tried to do. Distracted (and overwhelmed) with eTOC, I skipped giving a proper answer.  Thank you again.

Comment: Not my code :) As said in the edit the code is "taken from the package documentation" :) I thought it could help the question because it already had gathered two delete votes in the review queue.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Thank you!